# Error while defining custom pipes in the same file in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-pipe

I have a ts file in which I declare several pipes, as shown here:

```
    import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Pipe({ name: 'round' })
export class RoundPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(input: number) {
    return Math.round((input + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100;
  }
}

@Pipe({ name: 'fractionDigits' })
export class FractionDigitsPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(input: string, maximumFractionDigits: number) {
    return parseFloat(input).toFixed(maximumFractionDigits);
  }
}

@Pipe({ name: 'stripTags' })
export class StripTags implements PipeTransform {
  transform(input: string) {
    return input.replace(/<\/p>/gi, ' ').replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, '').replace(/&nbsp;/gi,' ');
  }
}

@Pipe({ name: 'camelize' })
export class Camelize implements PipeTransform {
  transform(str: string) {
    return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1).toLowerCase();
  }
}

@Pipe({ name: 'formatDate' })
export class FormatDate implements PipeTransform {
  transform(input: string) {
    return moment(input).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
  }
}

@Pipe({ name: 'dateTimeFormat' })
export class FormatDateTime implements PipeTransform {
  transform(input: string) {
    if (input === null) {
      return '';
    }
    return moment(input).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss');
  }
}

export function getBase64ImageFromURL(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
    img.onload = () => {
      const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.width = img.width;
      canvas.height = img.height;
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      const dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      resolve(dataURL);
    };
    img.onerror = error => {
      reject(error);
    };
    img.src = url;
  });
}
```

I created a `module` to import all of them from my `AppModule` file. This is my `pipes.module.ts` file:

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { StripTags, Camelize, FormatDate, FormatDateTime, FractionDigitsPipe, RoundPipe } from './models/helper';


@NgModule({
  imports: [],
  declarations: [
    StripTags,
    Camelize,
    FormatDateTime,
    RoundPipe,
    FormatDate,
    FractionDigitsPipe
  ],
  exports: [
    StripTags,
    Camelize,
    FormatDateTime,
    RoundPipe,
    FormatDate,
    FractionDigitsPipe
  ]
})
export class PipesModule {
  static forRoot() {
    return {
        ngModule: PipesModule,
        providers: [],
    };
}
}
```

And I add it into my `app.module.ts` main module file like this:

```
 imports: [
       .......
       PipesModule.forRoot(),
       .......
 ]
```

But then, when I try to use it, I get the following error for all pipes:

> ERROR in : The pipe 'xxx' could not be found

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the pipe under imports which you want to use in the **`app.module.ts`**

```
imports: [RoundPipe],
```

Comment: Each pipe? I'm using a custom PipeModule, which has all of them... so don't understand why I should import each of them instead of the PipesModule...

Comment: whatever you are using in that module

Comment: Even that, it keeps failing. That's not the solution I guess... :(